# Can we have a feature to allow commenting on Data Explorer queries?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I love http://data.stackexchange.com but sometimes, I want to collaborate with the query creator - perhaps suggesting why their query isn't working as expected or asking something about the query.

I don't know if comments is the appropriate form for this - perhaps a meta.data.stackexchange.com works instead or some other system, but I feel that something is lacking in this general area.

For example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/470/electorate-badge-progress) has a comment suggesting the data dump is broken - actually, I believe it's anonymized as it should be. However, I can't comment to clarify that.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, and would make the queries much more collaborative.

Comment: Easiest way to make these kind of things happen is to submit a patch

Comment: @waffles: Hmm, I [read recently](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/68740/whats-the-canonical-retort-to-its-open-source-submit-a-patch) that "submit a path" is no longer considered a valid answer to this type of question. ;-)

Comment: I have no idea to what I would be submitting a patch even if I created one.

Comment: @Cody strongly disagree with the sentiment around that top voted post on programmers, I did not mean to offend at all. Just strapped for time at the moment. If anyone patches this I will be happy to merge it in.

Comment: this is planned