# How can we identify the creator of Data Explorer query?

Tags: support, data-explorer

So far we do not have a possibility to comment on a SEDE queries. (Although there exists a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87531/can-we-have-a-feature-to-allow-commenting-on-data-explorer-queries) for this.) Another related post is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52887/notify-contact-sede-user-of-fix-to-query).

Until there is such a possibility, the only solution I can think about would be to ping the author on some other SE site about the query. (Which is not ideal - since the comment would be off-topic for that particular question - but the comment can be later removed and the discussion can be continued in chat. But even a solution which is not ideal is better than no solution.)

The problem is how to find the user who wrote the query, since I do not see any connection between the user page on Data Explorer and the network profile on SE.

Some of the users have given enough information in their profile so that they could be identified and their account on some SE site could be found.

The other possibility would be to try to use gravatar and Google Images search. (I have tested this on myself. When I put my gravatar from SEDE into Google Search, I [was not succesfull](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisspKmRFeiTtUekmhqYJnJeXi2BFqC5sdyFg85bmUDoKIBHlS-ENy-RriPpWeYb0uChqy64vZT4vzt6dGk9JsIwbjEYGbW7_1OtipOO0pspLP798wx3Cqa1iA8fKo7SNsYnapJyhC3okTed3nb3aWTSiwEOkBo6WDtFcxlqC6bmp7MZOG75hdwpKo3OVf6cB3KovrfQ6rBPakgoAUq1t6Yigji5Q0LIIRqyGwLLWgpFwZOAilI4RvgkAQ_1eeYqCkplvbkBD114C_1RokMrcGRA0qrSWKehFx0U9jnIZ1wdDDYBkRohdR3EWjtTenC7Sh1xgZuMITUg7ixuNX-L29-VotwRjRAfMg9LOFE3oL3Il-Nkh_1z2eO8kGG6NAmrB3ZSrls7caKO5RbwxCFHEzvSpd9CMuCm1xE1X4kNKe_1WMEi9MynJppAj16jfIUcyHxPyFGH_1GxovDrxyiuHkOxK6_1EXXWIKVbAPRgbhuGSj7iQ-C1IYQwrYq1w_1U-0DSsfV6NoqOPb85r5xCb2IuOHv_1NHdOUT9inqKjGBdM5h_1FAVPqFe6AbFXoajAyZC-PUsKw4MMrKa32Voy5RKsIRxBbf29xAzQz5FhRZyS7y_19q2GLCd377_19NsPETyHtm3Z0P--l_1echj4PlqOznNuF_11ocf8LxvTbmb82KKEOrkRPN0RFsF6PGJs1KcJvzpPxIT3jK0V4rNtxESn-RaGK4GLM2_1qmKimDf-CeVpsNR6t1iGxOGa2OFa7Ex86XYGyTMz3b41lbf6dcQrtatKAXmShH-emBzNu9A_1Gsl_14PUE9Krud_16dEUmkbSTcYKVNjPYv9TelWwxLrsy3pSwJoJygEvspRFhYcS8BNMrAlzlrRgWydxdIgb_1vewaVY1BLsidJ2ZObovQLne26opPP9o1JgDSayS6MG-7c2PBscBl1JcJJ0yRyo3y3qOcRRlewAr7NQBD5nIDhMxA9bYTJo4D6SK64qC5iRsss0yAHOo3t4hvnnCe8gSde46V6uI6xYnW4TSnSWzOkzn96J7boHkS7Hg5pxuB8_1_1fH1wcA-JZ4mxGe7zBYzDQMHcPrrNsNpli-d52TeRiGqtxJ-VPhfW5BTNWYkOWrUXKurH7FcbYakqhxMQA46DQmTuyWJS9lQH00H4QKik09ml7v2hUsJn-iE76F1vARNHGlD8UmCMNnHVVC7RCUHfwtWPtrwUxH1pUOvSUszf9bRJW4-S0Y6VCDN_1oNC47SByYQ).
However, after [restricting the search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&tbs=sbi%3AAMhZZisspKmRFeiTtUekmhqYJnJeXi2BFqC5sdyFg85bmUDoKIBHlS-ENy-RriPpWeYb0uChqy64vZT4vzt6dGk9JsIwbjEYGbW7_1OtipOO0pspLP798wx3Cqa1iA8fKo7SNsYnapJyhC3okTed3nb3aWTSiwEOkBo6WDtFcxlqC6bmp7MZOG75hdwpKo3OVf6cB3KovrfQ6rBPakgoAUq1t6Yigji5Q0LIIRqyGwLLWgpFwZOAilI4RvgkAQ_1eeYqCkplvbkBD114C_1RokMrcGRA0qrSWKehFx0U9jnIZ1wdDDYBkRohdR3EWjtTenC7Sh1xgZuMITUg7ixuNX-L29-VotwRjRAfMg9LOFE3oL3Il-Nkh_1z2eO8kGG6NAmrB3ZSrls7caKO5RbwxCFHEzvSpd9CMuCm1xE1X4kNKe_1WMEi9MynJppAj16jfIUcyHxPyFGH_1GxovDrxyiuHkOxK6_1EXXWIKVbAPRgbhuGSj7iQ-C1IYQwrYq1w_1U-0DSsfV6NoqOPb85r5xCb2IuOHv_1NHdOUT9inqKjGBdM5h_1FAVPqFe6AbFXoajAyZC-PUsKw4MMrKa32Voy5RKsIRxBbf29xAzQz5FhRZyS7y_19q2GLCd377_19NsPETyHtm3Z0P--l_1echj4PlqOznNuF_11ocf8LxvTbmb82KKEOrkRPN0RFsF6PGJs1KcJvzpPxIT3jK0V4rNtxESn-RaGK4GLM2_1qmKimDf-CeVpsNR6t1iGxOGa2OFa7Ex86XYGyTMz3b41lbf6dcQrtatKAXmShH-emBzNu9A_1Gsl_14PUE9Krud_16dEUmkbSTcYKVNjPYv9TelWwxLrsy3pSwJoJygEvspRFhYcS8BNMrAlzlrRgWydxdIgb_1vewaVY1BLsidJ2ZObovQLne26opPP9o1JgDSayS6MG-7c2PBscBl1JcJJ0yRyo3y3qOcRRlewAr7NQBD5nIDhMxA9bYTJo4D6SK64qC5iRsss0yAHOo3t4hvnnCe8gSde46V6uI6xYnW4TSnSWzOkzn96J7boHkS7Hg5pxuB8_1_1fH1wcA-JZ4mxGe7zBYzDQMHcPrrNsNpli-d52TeRiGqtxJ-VPhfW5BTNWYkOWrUXKurH7FcbYakqhxMQA46DQmTuyWJS9lQH00H4QKik09ml7v2hUsJn-iE76F1vARNHGlD8UmCMNnHVVC7RCUHfwtWPtrwUxH1pUOvSUszf9bRJW4-S0Y6VCDN_1oNC47SByYQ&q=site%3Astackexchange.com&oq=site%3Astackexchange.com&gs_l=serp.3...47488.52171.0.52515.30.26.4.0.0.0.296.2544.18j7j1.26.0....0...1c.1.30.serp..18.12.1116.kPjPU14-HcE) to the domain stackexchange.com, one of the results was my user page on one of of the SE sites.)

> - Is there an easier way to find the SE user who wrote a particular Data Explorer query?

Even if there is no strategy that would work in general, I would be interested in tips which might help at least in some cases.

Comment: Most users will use the same display name, e.g. [random user I checked](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/6705/beryllium?order_by=recent) and same name [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/194544/beryllium). Other than that nothing we can really do.